# Python QuTip: Plot full lines in Bloch sphere

Tags: python, qutip

I've recently started using QuTip for Python. I've want to plot the evolution of a two-level system in a Bloch sphere using `qutip.Bloch()`, but I don't know how to make such a plot as a continuous line.

This is the code I currently use:

```
bola = Bloch()
bola.add_points(pnts)
bola.point_marker = ['o']
bola.point_size=[8]
bola.show()
```

And of course I get a standard Bloch sphere with a lot of discrete points. Is there any way to join the points with a straight line?

Answer (score 2):

change the method to lines:

`bola.add_points(pnts,meth='l')`